# How to initialize array of pointers to classes?

Tags: c++, c++11

given class (for example in name of `X`) , I want to allocate array like that:
`X** array=new X*[20];`

Let's look about the following function:

```
void Func(){  
  X** array=new X*[2];  
  X[0]=& X(5);
  X[1]=& X(3);
}
```

Is it OK to do it like that or that I must to do it with `new`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ How do you set an array of pointers to null in an initialiser list like way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615071/c-how-do-you-set-an-array-of-pointers-to-null-in-an-initialiser-list-like-way)

Comment: @Ron I know that I can to do it with vector, but, I asking for array for learn how to work with it.

Comment: @Ron `X** array=new X*[20];` it's not defined as array of `20` pointers to `X`?

Comment: Edit note: The first part of the question was a duplicate - see Lanting's comment - so that is removed.  Please reconsider the close vote in light of the edit.

Comment: Side note: instead of raw array, have you considered `std::array` or `std::vector`? Both are less problematic than your raw pointers. If you combine them with smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, depending on use case), you do not have to care for correct object deletion either...

Comment: If you want pure array of 20 `nullptr`s to `X` => `X *arr[20] = {};` The `arr` is of type of array of 20 pointers to `X` and not a pointer to pointer to `X`

Comment: Does that even compile? You can't take the address of a temporary. And even if you could then no, it would not work. You would be using the address of a dead object.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, when you do something like this :

```
X foo(5);
X[0] = &foo;
```

(wich i suppose is what you want to say)

`X[0]` will take the adress of foo, wich is a local variable who will only exist in the scope of your function. And if i do not tell bullshit, does not compile. (`-fpermissive`)

So after the last instruction of your function, the usage of this pointer **will be Undefined**

You can't be sure after any allocation that the content of your data is equal to `nullptr` (*if not initialise yet*). Initialisation syntax have way different behavior depending language, compiler, stars position etc (just kidding for the last one) so make sure to read the documentation about it.
However you can be sure to init something with null Value by using a zero-initialisation. [Link here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55719b21ba05cc9a)

If you don't want to dynamicly allocate your array of pointer make sure that those pointer still valid during the lifetime of your object

Another solution could be to dynamicly allocate them.

```
X[0] = new X(5);
```

Comment: Can you expalin how can I do it without `new` for example? (or that I cant do it without `new`  [at all] because  is a temporary object )

Comment: @AskMath: That's not how programming works. You should first define what `array` is supposed to hold. If you just need two `X` objects, you'd define `X array[2];`. If for some reason you know you need to store two results of `new X`, you'd need `X* array[2]`.

Comment: @MSalters and for define `X* array[2]` I must to define a default constructor in X class?

Comment: @AskMath: You wouldn't even need the full definition of `class X`! You can use a forward declaration, i.e. `class X;`. The definition of `class X` is only needed when you need actual `X` objects - but again, normally this question does not crop up at all.

Comment: [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7417c0dcf9368aa)
is the implementation with some comments
@Jarod42 true i've edited my mistakes

Comment: @FabianleMaux: I've edited the markup in your question, but I disagree with the content. Zero initialization **will** make pointers equal to `nullptr`, it's just not the only possible initialization. This does not depend on compiler or platform.

Comment: @MSalters Can you explain what that you said please?

Comment: When you are talking about *Zero initialisation* are you talking about *non-initialisation* ? @MSalters

Comment: @FabianleMaux: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization. If you're not yet familiar enough with C++ to know these terms, you might find it hard to answer C++ questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: Edited thanks to you @MSalters