# How to init dynamic array of pointers to nullptr c++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I have a code:

```
var *item[8] = { nullptr };
```

and it works good. But i need to do this dynamically. This is what i tried:

```
int n = 8;
var **item;
item = new var*[n]();
item = { nullptr };
```

but this is not working. Where is the difference and what should i do?

//Sorry for my english

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/2615245/4045598.

Comment: Providing a value in the `{ }` only initialises the first element. This is a common misconception, where people think `bool arr[5] = { true };` will initialise them all to `true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `()` in `item = new var*[n]();` will [value-initialize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) all of the pointers to `nullptr` for you, so you don't need to do it manually afterwards.

```
int n = 8;
var **item;
item = new var*[n](); // <-- all are nullptr here
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/ucLVKT)

That said, you really should be using `std::vector` instead of `new[]` directly:

```
int n = 8;
std::vector<var*> item;
item.resize(n);
```

Or simply:

```
int n = 8;
std::vector<var*> item(n);
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/3cQMJ5)

Either way should initialize the pointers to `nullptr` as well.  But if you want to be explicit about it, you can do so:

```
int n = 8;
std::vector<var*> item;
item.resize(n, nullptr);
```

```
int n = 8;
std::vector<var*> item(n, nullptr);
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/peAtju)

Comment: Just item = new var*[8](); works only with 8 entered in code. But when i put variable it doesn't work

Comment: @shumik_UA [Works fine for me](https://ideone.com/ucLVKT), and it is standard behavior. So if it is not initializing correctly for you then it is probably a compiler bug.

Answer (score 2):

if you have an array, vector or a container in general and you want to fill it with some value whichever that is you can use the std::fill function:

```
std::fill(item,item+n,nullptr);
```

However if you want to assign nullptr at initialization time, it is much easier: you use [zero initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) and you are fine. Just be aware of the difference between zero and default initialization:

```
item = new var*[n]{};     //zero initialized (all elements would have nullptr as value)

item = new var*[n];       //default initialized (elements might not have nullptr as value)

item = new var*[n]();     //default initialized until C++03
                          //zero initialized after C++03
```

Anyway, I would suggest you to migrate to std::vector instead of C style arrays. You generally end up with much less error-prone code.

Comment: Thanks, of course i prefer to use vector. But it's not allowed in this task